# Oqpsk pll delay axis ambiguity

Tags: modulation, oqpsk

[image]
I don’t understand how this phenomenon appear in OQPSK carrier recovery loop. I found nothing on google. Is it a normal phenomenon in OQPSK loop or specific? Why does it get reversed I and Q? In the figure(b), why does the sampling point change?

Comment: What textbook is this?